# How to get a queryset of foreign keys from a current queryset in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have two models, Employee and Manager. The Employee model has a foreign key to Manager.

```
class Manager(models.Model):

    name = models.TextField()


class Employee(models.Model):

    name = models.TextField()

    manager = models.ForeignKey(
        Manager, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="manager"
    )
```

Given an arbitrary queryset qs of Employee objects, I would like to get a queryset of their managers. This seems very simple but I can't find a way to do it. In naive python, I could get a list of these managers by doing something like:

```
qs = Employee.objects.filter(whatever)
managerlist = []
for emp in qs:
    managerlist.append(emp.manager)
```

and this would give me a list of managers corresponding to employees in my queryset. But instead of a list I would like a queryset. Is there a quick simple way to do this?

Comment: Share your `Employee`  and `Manager` model.

Comment: have done just now

Answer (score 1):

```
manager_ids = qs.filter(manager_id__isnull=False).values_list('manager_id', flat=True)
Manager.objects.filter(id__in=manager_ids)
```

This should gives you a clean Manager queryset for any Employee queryset

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (only an example):

```py
Manager.objects.filter(employee__in=qs).values('id', 'name').distinct()
```

It would give you a queryset of distinct `Manager` objects that have at least one related `Employee` object in the qs queryset, with only the `id` and `name` fields included.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, the `related_name` should be something like `related_name="employees"` or `related_name="employee_set"` or whatever makes sense to you, remember "*related_name* is the name to be used for the relation from the related object back to the current one".

Now, if you really want to have a `queryset` of managers you can simply filter the managers you found in your previous query, for example:

```py
employee_qs = Employee.objects.filter(...)
manager_ids = set(emp.manager_id for emp in employee_qs)
manager_qs =  Manager.objects.filter(id__in=manager_ids)
```

Notice that to create the `manager_ids` set, `manager_id` is being used instead of `manager`, it is because we just need Manager's IDs.